# How do I add a license when building proprietary deb packages?

Tags: ubuntu, deb, dpkg

I have some code that I developed and built into a deb package.
However, unlike other packages when you double click it in Ubuntu the licence field shows up as "Unknown".  Instead I want it to say "Proprietary" like others.

I couldn't find anything in the control file definition that adds it.  And looking at other packages such as the nvidia ones that do say "Proprietary", I can't see anything in there that would add it.

How do I set a licence?